# Shift-k opens manual on keyword but ":verbose map <s-k>" shows no mapping

Tags: key-bindings

Question says it all. Why does vim report no mapping exists when a mapping does exist?

Comment: `:h 'keywordprg'` and `:h K`

Answer (score 2):

`:map` will only show mappings that were defined by a plugin/vim script or by you in your `.vimrc`. `K` is not a mapping, it's a command.

You probably did not find a help entry because you used the `<s-k>` syntax. Try `:help K` like Christian suggested.